# Proper projected coordinate system for Minnesota for measuring areas

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, united-states

I have seen in ArcGIS many different State Plane systems for Minnesota (location coordinates in WGS84: 44,07 lat/-94,61 long) within the Projected Coordinate system group:

- NAD 1983 (CORS 96) (Meters)
- NAD 1983 (CORS 96) (US Feet)
- NAD 1983 (CORS 96) (Intl Feet)
- NAD 1983 (Meters)
- NAD 1983 (US Feet)
- NAD 1983 (Intl Feet)
- NAD 1983 HARN (Meters)
- NAD 1983 HARN (US Feet)
- NAD 1983 NSRS2007 (Meters)
- NAD 1983 NSRS2007 (US Feet)

Which is the best choice for low area distortion?

Is that choice better than the UTM 15 N projection, for that purpose?

Comment: The difference between the Meters, US Feet, and International Feet is what _units_ the coordinate system is in; choosing a particular one is more a matter of project requirements than accuracy and they're essentially interchangeable. The different _datums_ can affect the accuracy of results by a few feet; the most recent update (and presumably most accurate) is the NSRS2007.

Answer (score 3):

These are all for the State Plane zones which are conformal (maintain shape, not area) like UTM. They should be slightly better because they're defined for a small area than a UTM zone is.

Even better, but still conformal, would be the [county-level Minnesota coordinate reference systems](http://www.dot.state.mn.us/surveying/toolstech/mapproj.html).

Instead using an equal area projection like Albers and customizing it for your area of interest would be a better solution.

Comment: Thanks. I see in ArcGIS that there are Albers projections for US within "Projected Coordinate Systems/Continental/North America", and "Projected Coordinate Systems/State Systems", but I don't see which can be used for Minnesota. Any help will be welcome.

Comment: Could you confirm that ArcGIS doesn't allow area measurement when working with a Geographic Coordinate System? I think I have read something about a recent ArcGIS improved functionality in that sense. I work with ArcGIS 10.1.

Comment: That's true. We blocked it as making no sense, but have now added calculating area based on geodesics back in again...post 10.2? I think.

Comment: Do you have any answer to the previous question: which Albers CRS can be used for Minnesota from "Projected Coordinate Systems/Continental/North America" or "Projected Coordinate Systems/State Systems" groups in ArcGIS?

Comment: I don't recall anything Minnesota-specific. As I mentioned in the answer, you should customize one for your area of interest.

Comment: And, what does customizing a Coordinate system involve? what do you mean with customizing a Coordinate system?

Comment: Defining a coordinate system by using defining parameters that are specific to the area of interest. I usually pick an existing one, then right click it and choose copy-and-modify--give it a new name too, so you'll recognize it.